# Anchor Link makes vertical Scroll Bar Dissapear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page I've made and when an anchor link is clicked the vertical scroll bar on the right disappears. How can I keep the scroll bar from disappearing? I need help. Here's the page that has the problem: http://panhandlechaptertscpa.com/SCROLL_PROBLEM
Click on the **About Us** tab and then the **Leadership** anchor link.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant parts of your code here. The code may change on the page you've linked, rendering potential answers useless for future visitors.

Comment: It looks like jScrollPane js issue, because initially your all content is hidden and when you click on Leadership link it will show leadership content block, and "jScrollPaneTrack" position is already set according to the position when it is hidden, jScrollPane js is not resetting it, which is the main cause of this bug.

Comment: Set up a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

try to understand the mechanism of jscrollpane and its api and implement it in a proper way.Problem will be solved. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I am not a programmer so need an answer in the coding I can understand. thanks so much.